# Quantum numbers in various situations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

In the following questions I will be only talking about spatial states so we can safely ignore the spin state.

1) First of all I want to ask why is it that 3 quantum numbers are all that is needed to specify a unique state in 3D? Because it is certainly not the case that you can only have 3 commuting observables. I suspect that it's akin to the fact that to specify a trajectory in 3D you can only have 3 components. But let me explore the following example: Suppose you have the infinite cubical well. According to an exercise I did some time ago, you can uniquely specify a state by $n_x,n_y,n_z$. However note that $[P_i,P_j] = 0$ for $i$ different from $j$. And $[H,P_i] = 0$ for every $i$. So what prevents us from constructing 6 sets of quantum numbers $n_x,n_y,n_z,p_x,p_y,p_z$ where the latter 3 are eigenvalues of the linear momentum operators. Im obviously missing something since we only needed the first 3 to specify a state.

2) Is the choice of quantum numbers unique? For example, in the 3D harmonic oscillator we could specify the state by $n_x,n_y,n_z$ or we could, as in the hydrogen atom case, specify it by $n,l,m_l$. Or for example in the infinite cubical well, we could specify a unique state by $n_x,n_y,n_z$ or (if my reasoning is somewhat correct) by $p_x,p_y,p_z$ am I right?

3) If only 3 quantum numbers are needed can we pick them arbitrarily (in case we have more than 3)? For example in the previous part I asked whether we can specify a state in the cubical well by $p_x,p_y,p_z$ but this gives us no information about the energy of the system for example. Should an energy state always be included as a quantum number and if so why?

4) Finally what happens when we don't have 3 commuting observables? Well, first of all, I suspect that in this case the problem is too hard to be solved analytically anyway? Because if we can't find three quantum numbers we can't identify or construct all these unique stationary states that we love. Technically speaking, a physical system doesn't have to have stationary states (since it may not have enough conserved quantities), it's just that when we have these states it make our life so much easier given that they span the state space, am I correct?

Comment: Energy eigenstates in an infinite well aren’t momentum eigenstates. Because the Hamiltonian isn’t purely kinetic energy. There’s a spatial dependent step function (limiting) as well.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. So their commutator is non-zero. But the question still stands whether we can construct more than 3 sets of quantum numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I can at least say that the choice of quantum number is not unique and that the number of quantum number does not have to be equal to the dimension $d$. This is because all powers of $\mathbb{N}$ are countable, so there exists a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^d$, which means that you could cast all $d$ quantum numbers into a unique one.

For instance, consider the $2d$ harmonic oscillator with quantum numbers $n_x, n_y$, and define a new quantum number $N$:

$$N = \frac{(n_x + n_y)(n_x + n_y +1 )}{2} + n_y$$

Btw, this is the standard mapping of $\mathbb{N}^2$ onto $\mathbb{N}$. See the picture below:

[image: mapping N^2 onto N]

With the inverse transformation:

$$n_x, n_y = d(N) - \left( N - \frac{d(N)(d(N)+1)}{2} \right), \left( N - \frac{d(N)(d(N)+1)}{2} \right)$$

where $d(N) = \mathrm{floor}\left(-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{1 + 8N}}{2}\right)$ correspond to the number of the "diagonal", which is $n_x + n_y$.

Even simpler than this (and generalizable to any number of dimensions), sort the energies of your Hamiltonian from the lowest to the highest (if degenerate energies, sort them in any order), and associate a new quantum number $N$ with eigenvalue $n$ associated with the $n$-th lowest energy.

You can even go in the opposite direction, and define for instance two quantum numbers $n_x$ and $n_y$ for the $1d$ harmonic oscillator by plugging your single quantum number $n$ into the reciprocal formula above.

In short, there is no definitive choice of quantum numbers, neither is there a unique choice of number of quantum numbers in dimension $d$.

---

Now, why do we often choose $d$ quantum numbers to describe a $d$-dimensional system? This is where I am not sure of all the reasons, but I can see a few:

- for a separable Hamiltonian ($V = V_x(x) + V_y(y) + V_z(z)$), you can obviously simply diagonalize the Hamiltonian in each direction. Because in $1d$, energies are not degenerate, you can unambigously sort the eigenstates for each direction depending on their energy, and associate a quantum number $n_x$ with it. While you *could* cast all three quantum numbers $n_x, n_y, n_z$ into a single one as shown above, by keeping the three separate numbers, it is way way easier to visualize the quantum state. Large $n_x$ means that the wavefunction will probably be extended along $x$, and if $n_y$ and $n_z$ are small, it probably means that it is well-localized in these two directions (of course it depends on the exact shape of the potential, but you got the idea).
- Similarly, even when the system is not separable, such as for the hydrogen atom for instance, we like to think of the state (when possible), in terms of classical coordinates. I am oversimplifying quite a bit, but the three quantum numbers $n$, $l$ and $m_l$ mostly gives you information about the radial, polar and azimutal behavior of the wavefunction respectively, corresponding to classical coordinates $r$, $\theta$ and $\phi$.